API controller - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
This happened after I changed project name in the solution explore.(renamed from "MyFirstQuestion0513" to "Flora_Assignment1")

I saw the error line in one cs file and opened it and updated the name.


Instead of creating a new project, is there a way to figure out the issue?

Can you please correct the 'image descriptions' on the screenshot links

I'd like to, but I've no idea how to do that. Sorry, that's my first time being here. I either dragged the image or clicked img icon there, but both did not work. I'd appreciated if you can advise.

There should be a image icon you can select in the textarea menu as you are writing. I have managed to edit for you

wow, you are able to edit mine, that's so smart!!!
